# How can I set the height for window split?

Tags: vim

`:sp` horizontally splits the current window in two.

How can I set the **height** of the new window?

I am imagining something like:

```
:sp --width=30
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By preceding the `:split` with a number, you can set the height:

```
" Split a 10-line height window above:
:10split

" Or to open the new viewport below the current
:below 10split
```

From `:help split`:

```
:[N]sp[lit] [++opt] [+cmd]                              :sp :split
                Split current window in two.  The result is two viewports on
                the same file.  Make new window N high (default is to use half
                the height of the current window)
```